# Difference between Bootloader .map and Application .map files

Tags: bootloader

When you compile a bootloader code or an application code with xc32, .map files are generated.

What are the main differences between them ? (.map for Bootloader and .map for application code).

I don't have a microchip at home so I can't try it. Any idea or link instead of [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002186A.pdf) ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are MAP files, so, they have the same general format and contain information about symbols from your code (their names, types, sizes, sections, relative and absolute addresses).

The difference here will mostly be the addresses used - bootloader uses some addresses and the application uses some (other) addresses. Also, typically, you will use different libraries (or "run-times") for bootloader and for application, so, apart from your own symbols (from your code) which can be the same in both cases, you will have (some) different library symbols.